# How do I connect excel powerquery to a postgres database

Tags: postgresql, powerquery, npgsql

I need to connect powerquery to a postgres database in order to clean and have automated access to the data for excel reports.

I've tried: Get Data - From Database - From PostgreSQL database

This tells me I need npgsql, which takes me to github. However I'm not sure how to install that from github. I downloaded the zip file but I don't know what to do to install it on my computer.

I've also searched google and youtube, which I thought would definitely give me the answer, but no luck so far.

Comment: Could you provide more information? NpgSQL should already be part of your Powerquery install (unless you installed Power BI before 2019). Then you will also need to use a gateway.